# Using plantuml within a markdown document

Tags: markdown, plantuml

At the moment I am trying to make a presentation using markdown.

In order to include an UML diagram I want to use PlantUML.

The code is written in the document below. I am of the understanding, that this should work. However it does not.

Of course there is a solution to create the UML diagrams outside separately and include the in markdown. This however would make the document less self contained.

#### Markdown code

Here is (part of) the code:

````
---
Previous slide

---

# diagram

```plantuml
@startuml
  class Example {
    - String name
    - int number 
    
    +void getName()
    +void getNumber()
    +String toString()
  }
@enduml
```

---
Next slide

---
````

[This blog post](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/inserting-uml-in-markdown-using-vscode/) suggests that this should work.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) has no support for PlantUML (or LaTeX, or Mermaid, or anything like that). Some _implementations_ have added support for things like this. Which Markdown implementation are you trying to use? What makes you think this should work?

Comment: Several sites seem to suggest that this is possible. (e.g. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/inserting-uml-in-markdown-using-vscode/). But you are right to suggest that this may depend on implementations. I am using the standard markdown version that is provided by visual studio code.

Comment: Is this question specifically about the VS-code plugin, or about rendering PlantUML inside Markdown files? Please be more specific what does not work and [edit] to ask a specific question.

Answer (score 12):

Installing 2 additional extensions was required for me to get this to work:

[markdown extension pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bat67.markdown-extension-pack)

[markdown plantuml preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=myml.vscode-markdown-plantuml-preview)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30437863)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you linked to doesn't say that PlantUML support is built into Markdown, or even into the VSCode Markdown plugin. It asks you to install an extension:

> With a single extension, you can visualize UML diagrams in VS Code's preview panel.
>
> That extension is called **plantuml**, and you can install it either by searching for it in the extensions panel… or simply by running the following from a terminal pane…
>
> ```
> ext install plantuml
> ```

Install the `plantuml` extension then try again.

Comment: Installing (and re-installing) PlantUML does not work. It is possible to make UML diagrams directly using this tool, but it does not work within a markdown document.

Comment: @Heijne, I'm just seeing this comment now. Did you install the Visual Studio Code _extension_ called `plantuml`? It sounds like you're installing the standalone tool.

Answer (score 1):

The VSCode extension, Markdown-PDF will export a Markdown file to PDF and HTML.

The extension supports PlantUML and also Mermaid.

Check the extension's page for how to begin & end PlantUML blocks, you don't need ```

More info here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzane.markdown-pdf

Also, since June 2021, VSCode supports KaTeX in Markdown:
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_58#_math-formula-rendering-in-the-markdown-preview

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a CLI tool to allow you to embed PUML diagrams into your code https://github.com/danielyaa5/puml-for-markdown

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ***VSCode***, you need install extensions:

1. [Markdown Plantuml Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=myml.vscode-markdown-plantuml-preview)
2. [Markdown Preview Enhanced](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shd101wyy.markdown-preview-enhanced)

Then download [Plantuml Jar](https://plantuml.com/download)

**Open VSCode**: 
Press ***F1***, search and choose ***Open User Settings*** 
Search ***markdown-preview-enhanced.plantumlJarPath*** 
Set path for Plantuml Jar 
Example: C:\plantuml-gplv2-1.2023.12.jar

Try code and preview:

````
```plantuml
A -> B: abc
```
````

> Prerequisite: You have installed and set the path for java

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [(at the time of writing) top voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66942718/6377268) and [the blog post](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/inserting-uml-in-markdown-using-vscode/) linked in your question, you first need to install the [PlantUML plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jebbs.plantuml).

After doing so, previewing `.puml` files worked for me, however, previewing `.md` files containing PlantUML code in code blocks as described in the linked blog post didn't work. If I understand you correctly, this is exactly what you experienced.

The symptoms match the ones described in [issue #449](https://github.com/qjebbs/vscode-plantuml/issues/449) and [issue #426](https://github.com/qjebbs/vscode-plantuml/issues/426) of the plugin repository. The rough gist:

- Rendering `.puml` files uses a local PlantUML renderer installed on your machine, which works out of the box.
- Rendering PlantUML diagrams in `.md` files is done using a remote server (the local renderer does not work for some reason), **whose URL needs to be manually entered into your VSCode configuration**.

Suggested fix: You need to provide a URL for the "PlantUML server" in configuration, see [this comment on issue #449](https://github.com/qjebbs/vscode-plantuml/issues/449#issuecomment-975520835) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the same thing in VS Code.  After I installed the `PlantUml` extension, I also installed [`Markdown Preview Enhanced`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shd101wyy.markdown-preview-enhanced) extension.  This is mentioned on the [blog post](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/inserting-uml-in-markdown-using-vscode/) under **Further functionality** section.

Answer (score 0):

I have used two ways (in VSCode) to do presentations with PlantUML diagrams, both with reveal.js as an engine and markdown as a format:

1. [VSCode-reveal extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=evilz.vscode-reveal) - the latest version supports PlantUML in the markdown.
   [image]
2. [Quarto presentations in revealjs](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/) is a very powerful tool, and as such requires much more configuration (but the documentation and support is superb). You have to also install a [pandoc filter called diagram-generator](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/diagram-generator) to support the PlantUML inside the markdown.
   [image]